# On exit from app, thread halts as Suspended (exception NullPointerException)

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I have an app that uses a thread with the following code:
@Override
public void run ()
{
    Canvas canvas=null;

```
while (running)
{
    try {
        canvas=surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (surfaceHolder)
        {
            {
                GenerateScan(canvas);
                processRequest=false;
            }
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (canvas!=null)
        {
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    } //<<<<<<<<<

}
}
```

The application seems to run fine, but when I touch the back arrow on the screen the application seems to end normally but after a short period shows a message "Unfortunately, xxxx has stopped". When I run it with the tablet connected to the emulator, processing halts at the end of the "finally" section (marked with <<< above) with the message in the Debug tab:

```
Thread[<12> nnnViewThread](Suspended(exception NullPointException))
```

Comment: Is that android? blackberry? Please add the relevant tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join the thread when the surface is destroyed (via back button press).
on surfaceDestroyed(), do something like this:

```
    boolean retry = true;

    if (thread != null)
    {
        thread.running = false;
        while (retry) 
        {
            try 
            {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.v("EXCEPTION ON_SURFACE_DESTROYED!", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    thread = null;
    activity.finish();
```